# Julia: Replacing a number with a string in an array

Tags: python, arrays, replace, julia

I have an array of number (integer or float) values (it's actually a column in a DataFrame object) and would like to replace, for example, all instances of 0 to "NaN" or some text. (Or convert 1-->"M" and 2-->"F".)

I am running into the problem that when I write `array[i] = "text"`, I get the error:

```
`convert` has no method matching convert(::Type{Int64}, ::ASCIIString)
```

How do I get around this? Also, what is the most efficient way of doing an equivalent of Pandas' `df.column.replace({1:"M", 2:"F"}, inplace=True)`?

I did try this:

```
df[:sex] = [ {1 => "M", 2 => "F"}[i] for i in df[:sex] ]
```

... but this runs into a problem when I am only replacing some of the values (then I get "key X not found" error, since I am passing a value from [:sex] that is not in my dict).

Comment: I don't know if there's more a Julian way to replace in columns, but you could use the `get` method -- i.e. `get(replace_dict, i, i)` -- to avoid the missing-key error in the same way you would use `replace_dict.get(i, i)` in Python.

Comment: I don't think you can do a simple replace operation because the contents of a column in a `DataFrame` must all be the same Type. I think you will need to create an entirely new column of type `Union(Number, String)` or type `Any`, if you want to mix numbers and strings in the same column. If the column is already of type `Any`, then what is wrong with `if blah == 0; blah = "NaN"; end` (inside a loop down the column)?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a start:

```
df[:sex] = convert(DataArray{Union(Int64, ASCIIString), 1}, df[:sex])

df[df[:sex] .== 1, :sex] = "M"
df[df[:sex] .== 2, :sex] = "F"
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you're better off with a [`PooledDataArray`](https://github.com/JuliaStats/DataArrays.jl):

> `PooledDataArray{T}`: A variant of `DataArray{T}` optimized for representing arrays that contain many repetitions of a small number of unique values -- as commonly occurs when working with categorical data.

...it is equivalent to a Categorical in pandas/R.

---

```
julia> df = DataFrame([1 3; 2 4; 1 6])
3x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | x1 | x2 |
|-----|----|----|
| 1   | 1  | 3  |
| 2   | 2  | 4  |
| 3   | 1  | 6  |

julia> PooledDataArray(DataArrays.RefArray(df[:x1]), [:Male, :Female])
3-element DataArrays.PooledDataArray{Symbol,Int64,1}:
 :Male
 :Female
 :Male

julia> df[:x1] = PooledDataArray(DataArrays.RefArray(df[:x1]), [:Male, :Female])
3-element DataArrays.PooledDataArray{Symbol,Int64,1}:
 :Male
 :Female
 :Male

julia> df
3x2 DataFrames.DataFrame
| Row | x1     | x2 |
|-----|--------|----|
| 1   | Male   | 3  |
| 2   | Female | 4  |
| 3   | Male   | 6  |
```

*Note: this works because the reference array contains values from 1 to the size of the labels (2).*